# Help interpreting logistic regression table

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation

[image: Table 5]

I don't understand the subscript where it describes how the predictor variables are coded. Instead of male = 0, female = 1, shouldn't it be male = 1, female = 0? Since being male appears to increase the odds of disciplinary action by 51%?

Comment: Yes, that's what it seems.

Comment: The descriptions of the binary predictors and the alleged coding appear to be systematically opposite for every predictor.  Since none of the results are significant (after correcting for five simultaneous tests) perhaps the best conclusion you can draw from this table is "the study wasn't large enough to tell us anything."  If you agree, then at least you won't have to figure out what the table is trying to say!

Comment: Here's the full paper: https://medicine.osu.edu/sitetool/sites/pdfs/studentaffairspublic/Unprofesssional_Behavior_State_Medical_Board.pdf

Comment: Do you need to correct for multiple comparisons- the results are from a logistic regression? Also, I do think that they concluded professionalism is statistically significant.